# Buttons inside ListPicker

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, toolkit

I have ListPicker where each item is musical instrument. Only one item simultaneously can be selected. In each item beside instrument name there is also button which plays preview sample.

ListPicker template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ListFullModeItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <c4f:RoundButton Grid.Column="0" Tag="{Binding Id}" ImageSource="/Content/AppBarIcons/play.png" Click="instrumentPreview_Click" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="35"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Unfortunately clicking on button automatically closes ListPicker dialog which is not what I want. I thought about marking instrumentPreview_Click event as handled but RoutedEventArgs doesn't have such property in WP7 (unlike WPF)

Comment: Although the answer from Pedro Lamas will probably work, I don't think it's smart to override the expected behavior. Users expect to tap on a listpicker item to select something. I'd suggest you open up a new page with a list of your items and from there clicking on the item selects it, and clicking on the button plays the sound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `Click` event, use the `Tap` event: you'll get a [GestureEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.gestureeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instance with a [Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.gestureeventargs.handled%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property that you can set to `true`!